# Django prefetch related used inside a serializer method making too many queries. How to use prefetch related to reduce queries in following case?

Tags: python, django, query-optimization, response-time, django-prefetch-related

By investigating why some apis are taking too much time to respond I encountered that it's because of the db queries increases as the queryset increases. In Django select related and prefetch related will helps to reduce this problem.
Here I am trying to solve such a problem where I used prefetch related in a serializer and still making too much db queries.

models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    orderid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    #....

class SubOrder(models.Model):
    suborderid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    orderid = models.ForeignKey(
        Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="orderitems", db_column="orderid"
    )
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    product_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    #....
```

views.py

```
class GetOrderDetailsByStore(mixins.ListModelMixin, generics.GenericAPIView):

  
    def get(self, request, order_number=None, *args, **kwargs):

        start = time.time()
        logger.info("started %s", start)
        store_id = self.kwargs["storeid"]
        status_list = [SubOrder.Suborder_Status.PAYMENT_INITIATED,
                       SubOrder.Suborder_Status.PAYMENT_FAILED,
                       SubOrder.Suborder_Status.PAYMENT_PENDING,
                       SubOrder.Suborder_Status.ORDER_INITIATED]
        
        order_items = Order.objects.filter(Q(storeid=store_id) &~Q(order_status__in=status_list)).order_by(
                "-created_date"
            )
        order_items_eager_loading = AllOrderSellerSerializer.setup_eager_loading(
                order_items)
        serializer = AllOrderSellerSerializer(order_items_eager_loading, many=True).data

        end = time.time()
        diff = end - start
        logger.info("ended %s", end)
        logger.info("time taken %s", diff)
        return Response({"message": "success", "data": serializer}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

serializer.py

```
class AllOrderSellerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    orderitems = AllOrderItemsSellerSerializer(many=True)
    store_reference = serializers.CharField(source="store_reference.store_reference")
    user_reference = serializers.CharField(source="user_reference.user_reference")
    number_of_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField("get_number_of_items")

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["order_number", "order_request_number", "store_reference",
                  "user_reference","number_of_items", "total_amount", "orderitems"]

    @staticmethod
    def get_number_of_items(obj):
        list_of_pdt_quantity_of_order = [order_item.product_quantity for order_item in obj.orderitems.filter(orderid=obj.orderid)]
        total_ordered_products_quantity = sum(list_of_pdt_quantity_of_order)
        return total_ordered_products_quantity
        # return obj.orderitems.count()


    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        """ Perform necessary eager loading of data. """
        queryset = queryset.prefetch_related('orderitems')
        queryset = queryset.select_related('user_reference', 'store_reference')
        return queryset
```

Here the number_of_items field takes the sum of prodcut_quantity. But here the db queries get increased as the orders increases.
if this "number_of_items" removed this takes only 2 queries for any number of orders, but because of this field queries get increasing and api taking much time to respond.
Does this using prefetch related in a wrong way or is there any way to solve this much of db queries?

[image: Django toolbar image is here.]

Answer (score 0):

`prefetch_related` will **not** reduce the number of SQL queries, this behaviour is [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> `select_related` works by creating an SQL join and including the fields of the related object in the `SELECT` statement. [...]
>
> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using `select_related`, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one relationships that are supported by `select_related`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. In documentation it's mentioned that "any subsequent chained methods which imply a different database query will ignore previously cached results, and retrieve data using a fresh database query". I understand that's the reason why it's causing this db queries and prefetch won't help here.  Is there any way to get the field "number_of_items " without doing much queries?

Comment: No idea, but you may consider re-organising the query to filter on the `SubOrder` model, and adding `select_related` for the `Order`. As a side note using a `ForeignKey` field name that ends with`id` is an antipattern. Django will append an `_id` to it and the database column name will be `orderid_id`. It is best to call it `order` as it is an `Order` instance.